# Is it possible to know what drives is my Solaris using?

Tags: solaris

I do not have access to the physical server.

I have access to a terminal (via PuTTY) where i can run commands. Is there any command that i can run to determine what hard drives my SunOS 5.11 is using? Is it RAID X? Or on SSD?

I run `raidctl -l` at the command line, but there is nothing returned. Does this mean that it is not on RAID?

I tried `format` command, but i got this:

```
~# format
Searching for disks...done
No disks found!
```

I did run `format` as root.

I can't find `devfsadm` utility. It has most probably been intentionally removed/not installed?. It's not in `/usr/sbin` and `/usr/bin`, and there is just a shared object `SUNW_fssnap_link.so` in this directory `/usr/lib/devfsadm/linkmod`.

I can't find how to get `devfsadm` installed. I am not a sysadmin and I do not have a sysadmin at hand. I have been trying randomly `pkg install`, `pkgadd`, without success. :/

Update 3:
Lambert, thanks. I tried what you mention:

```
# prtconf -v
System Configuration:  Oracle Corporation  sun4v
Memory size: 261120 Megabytes
System Peripherals (Software Nodes):

prtconf: devinfo facility not available
```

```
# cfgadm -alv
-bash: cfgadm: command not found
```

```
virtinfo
NAME            CLASS
non-global-zone current
logical-domain  parent
logical-domain  supported
```

```
zpool status
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        rpool                    ONLINE       0     0     0
          c0t5000CCA0164D1C80d0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

What can I deduce from that please?

**FINAL UPDATE**
Great, thanks Lambert(and Andrew)!!.
 Finally, found the answer. So the zpool command tells that it's configured as a non-RAID, and the iostat -En tells me the Vendor and Product name, which then tells me that it is a HDD and not a SSD.

Lambert, if you can post the answer, i will accept it.

Comment: Did you run `format` as `root`?

Comment: Try running [`devfsadm -C`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29031/devfsadm-1m.html), again as root.  Try it first as `devfsadm -C -v -s` to run it in verbose mode and suppress any changes.

Comment: Other possibilities to look at are: `/etc/path_to_inst`, `prtdiag` and/or `prtconf -v`, `cfgadm -alv`. Perhaps you are logged in onto a non-global zone with limited privileges and without assigned disks. Try `virtinfo` to see current mode. And Solaris uses ZFS as filesystem, recommended without hardware RAID. Try `zpool status` to find out how the ZFS pool is configured.

Comment: It appears that you are logged into a non-global zone. The zpool status command shows one disk. You can try to use `iostat -En` to find out the vendor of the disk. An other possibility is to contact the administrator of the global zone (logical domain) and ask the desired information

Comment: The zpool is configured as non-RAID, otherwise you would have seen two or more disks under rpool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `format` doesn't report any disks you might be logged into a non-global zone. To verify this you can run `virtinfo` to see if that's true.

Solaris 11 always uses ZFS as root filesystem. Use `zpool status` to find out how it's configured.

Using `iostat -En` it is possible to get the Vendor and Product for a device.

According to the updates in the original post the host used is a non-global zone:

```
virtinfo
NAME            CLASS
non-global-zone current
```

and the ZFS pool `rpool` is contructed of using just one disk:

```
NAME                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
rpool                    ONLINE       0     0     0
  c0t5000CCA0164D1C80d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

So no software RAID is being used. Please note that it is possible that hardware RAID is in effect but ZFS recommends to use software RAID for self healing capabilities of the pools to be activated.